# HttpClient in .netcore is automatically adding a space in header

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient, space, .net-core

I'm using `HTTPClient` in .netcore but I'm facing an issue when I add a custom accept header.

```
 var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)};
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

But after this, what I see is that a space has been automaticaly added, resulting in "`application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json; charset=ISO-8859-1`".   That space is causing me a trouble because the server return me an error. Without that space it works.

There is any way to remove that space in `HttpClient` header? Conventional ways do not work, like `trim`, or just a `replace` once it's inside a `DefaultRequestHeaders` and I can't modify directly.

Comment: I don't think so. It sounds strange though. The server should accept it. Spaces are allowed according to the standard.

Comment: I think too. But sadly the UOL servers don't accept with space. I Tested also on postman. But thanks for the comment Patrick

Comment: What is UOL...?

Comment: It's a Brasilian payment solution. I'm already entered in contact with them. But i'm still waiting an answer. The full name of the payment provider is PagSeguro. For international payment i'm using Paypal. But for Brasil, paypal dont support direct Credit Card Payment.

Comment: what if add header per request using HttpRequestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation ?

Comment: Even using with HttpRequestMessage. Have any other class to make a post request in .netcore?

Comment: This behavior is hardcoded into HttpClient. See here:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Unix/CurlHandler.EasyRequest.cs#L744

Comment: Thanks all the comments. i was able to turnarroud this issue making a new microservice with .net framework 4.5 and HTTPWebRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to turnarround this issue by making a new microservice with .net Framework 4.5. Using HttpWebRequest, the header dont add an automaticaly space between the charset and accept.

Thanks for the help =D

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in corefx.

Still open after 3 years!

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39260