# Post with Accept Header .Net Core 3.1 - PagSeguro

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I'm trying to integrate with a payment gateway (PagSeguro), according to the documentation, I must use the Accept Header "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1".

Trying with the code not work:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1");
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "application/json");
var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(enderecoPreApprovals, content);
var responsestr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I also tried using the same code from documentation:

```
var client = new RestClient(url) {Timeout = -1};
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1");
request.AddParameter("application/json", content, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

and using flurl:

```
var response = await addresPreApprovals
                    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1")
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .PostJsonAsync(adesaoDto);
```

All the responses are `Accept header field is mandatory.`. It's like Accept Header is not recognized.

The problem is not in API why i tried using Postman and Insomnia and it's works perfectly.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the space between the **semicolon** (;) and the word **charset**. We were unable to make it work in .NET 3.1 and there is even an issue on github, indicating that it is not a problem, an implementation of the RFC 7231 specification. Whenever a string "var1 = val1; var2 = val2", o is indicated. NET converts to "var1 = val1; var2 = val2". However, in .NET 5.0, an implementation was released that allows entering a raw string. Another option, according to an old post, is to create something with .NET Framework 4.5

In .NET 5.0

```
    var acceptValue = "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v1+json;charset=ISO-8859-1";
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, urlApprovals);
    requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", acceptValue);
```

GitHub ref: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30171

User who solved the problem using .NET Framework 4.5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40162071/2112736